# Android Studio TFS (team foundation server)

Tags: android, plugins, tfs, android-studio

We use TFS 2012 in our company for version controling.
According to this discussion:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/C_Gc6hVkig0
TFS plugin should come for the version 1.0, that is already released.
Any news?

---

**UPDATE**
Now we have TFS 2013 and use git. Everything works fine.

For anyone who still needs this checkout these news
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/10/23/team-foundation-plugin-for-intellij-idea.aspx

The plugin is in preview with an anticipated release in early 2016.
It seems that plugin lacks support of Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC): only Git is supported.

For TFS version control try this one [Team Foundation Server - Version Control Integration](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7961?pr=androidstudio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-visual-studio-team-services now supports TFS Integration (TFS Version Control and Git) with Android Studio and all community and enterprise versions of Jet Brains IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

no new news
 it's now in version 1.0.2 and no TFS added only **intelliJ IDEA ultimate** edition

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we should wait for version 1.2. [1.1 preview annouce](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio11preview1released) says that version will have IntelliJ 14 and (I hope) possibly the TFS plugin will work. On [issue I opened](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81707&q=tfs&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) last month no updates until now

Comment: Ok, hope so. Thanks, I've starred the issue

Comment: Yesterday I gave a try of Android Studio 1.2 with IntelliJ IDEA 14 (http://tools.android.com/ ) . TFS plugin and it is still broken. So I made a check on my issue open on android bug fix (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81707&can=1&q=tfs&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars ) and now it result as "Declined" and reason is "It will not be available for free in Android Studio"

Comment: I also gave a try and wrote about it under your issue. I suggest to create Android Studio Ultimate Edition with full functionality. What can we do for now? Will merge to tfs 2013 solve the problem?