# Team Foundation Server - Version Control Integration threw an uncaught UnsatisfiableDependenciesException

Tags: android, android-studio, tfs

I'm getting a lot of Team Foundation Server Error while doing anything for version control. Like checking out files, importing code from tfs etc.

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.3 and TFS Plugin Version: 0.3.0.302.

[image]

I've visited [Android Studio TFS (team foundation server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420905/android-studio-tfs-team-foundation-server) but didn't get the point. Please help what is going wrong!

Answer (score 0):

I have set up a same environment, and always got error:

[image]

Or error:

[image]

But when modify files, there is still a pending change in TFS. I don't think you are doing anything wrong, you can check the note on website https://intellijtfsplugin.codeplex.com/:

> - Disconnected server Workspaces have issues, as they don't always come    back online correctly..
> - Synchronize to Team Foundation server doesn't correctly refresh all    files's status.
> - Many of the context menu items still need code behind them.

This plugin still under developing, you can get source code from this website and have a review of it.